# how to factoring/group php methods

Tags: php, class, methods, factoring

I've got a PHP class which contains different methods:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class SuperAdminController extends Controller {

  public function name1Action($wanted = ''){
    $o = new name1Controller();
    self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
  }
   ...
  public function name10Action($wanted = ''){
    $o = new name10Controller();
    self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
  }

  private function routeWanted($wanted,$o,$that){
    switch($wanted){
      do something...
    }
  }

}
```

How can I group all my public function as one function like

```
public function name1Action ... name10Action($wanted = ''){
    $o = new name1Controller();
    self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [__call Magic](https://www.php.net/__call).

```
class SuperAdminController extends Controller {

    public function __call($name, $args){
        // list of method names
        $mNames = [
            'name1Action' => 1,
            'name2Action' => 2,
            'name3Action' => 3,
            /* ... */
        ];
        if (isset($mNames[$name])) {
            $o = new {$name}();
            return $this->nameAction($args[0], $o);
        }
    }

    protected function nameAction($wanted = '', $o){
        self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,  I was looking for something magic like that...it does the job

Answer (score 1):

You could use variable variables to solve this:

```
function Action($controller, $wanted = '') {
    $c = "{$controller}Controller";
    $o = new $c();
    // ...
}
```

then you could use:

```
$s = new SuperAdminController();
$s->Action('name1');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FdP55)

Comment: Thanks, it looks another way too.I don't know if there is a best practices for this case? Anyway I used __call which do the job

Comment: @Ben both are valid, the `__call` solution gives cleaner code I think. Sherif had already posted that solution so I wanted to show an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like the below:

```php
namespace App\Controllers;

class SuperAdminController extends Controller {

//    public function name1Action($wanted = ''){
//        $o = new name1Controller();
//        self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
//    }
...
//    public function name10Action($wanted = ''){
//        $o = new name10Controller();
//        self::routeWanted($wanted,$o,$this);
//    }

    public function beforeRouteWanted($wanted, $number) {
        $class = 'name' . $number . 'Controller';
        $o = new $class();
        self::routeWanted($wanted, $o, $this);
    }

    private function routeWanted($wanted,$o,$that){
        switch($wanted){
        do something...
        }
    }

}
```